# Error formatting EditText output

Tags: android, formatting, bundle

I have modified my activity to format the EditText output using a custom method called `round` but when I call the method on setting the results to the EditTexts I get the error:
`The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (double)` .I have gathered from this that there is a problem with adding the extra parameter of `2` when using `settext` but I'm not sure how else to output the results.My question is how in this case would I output the results when using this `round` function?

```
public class CalcResult extends MainActivity
{
    EditText result1,result2;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        result1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
        result2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        double mark1 = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
        double mark2 = intent.getDoubleExtra("number2", 0);


        //set the variables on EditTexts like this :
        result1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
        result2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2);

        result1.setText(round(mark1,2));
        result2.setText(round(mark2,2));
    }

    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }


}
```

Comment: use `String.ValueOf(double)`

Comment: In what context would I use `String.ValueOf(double)` ? @Raghunandan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not
>   applicable for the arguments (double)

Use

```
double r1 = round(mark1,2);
result1.setText(String.valueOf(r1)); 
double r2 = round(mark2,2);
result1.setText(String.valueOf(r2));
```

`setText(CharSequence)` takes a CharSequence as a param while you have a  `round(mark1,2)` returning double.

java docs

```
public static String valueOf(double d)
Returns the string representation of the double argument.
The representation is exactly the one returned by the Double.toString method of one argument.

Parameters:
d - a double.
Returns:
a string representation of the double argument.
See Also:
Double.toString(double)
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting the following error `The method ValueOf(double) is undefined for the type String` .Any idea what to do here?

Comment: @user2815899 how did you use the same like this `String.valueOf(round(mark1,2)`?

Comment: Yes I used it like this:  `result1.setText(String.valueOf(round(mark1,2)); ` but getting that error

Comment: @user2815899 check the edit now and make sure your round method returns double and not a string. if your round method returns a double it should work

Comment: Okay,I understand now it was passing back a string instead of the required double value. Thanks :)

Comment: @user2815899 and you have `public static double round` meaning return type is double if its string you should change your return type to string and there is not need for String.valueOf in that case. but in your case http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html returns double value.

Comment: Also how would I modify this output to include the measurement format.I tried ` result2.setText(round(mark2 + "inches",2));` but that didn't work as the round() method only takes params(double,int).How would I edit this to include the hardcoded string for the measurement format? Thanks

Comment: @user2815899 why did you unaccept and why should i answer if you don't accept?

Comment: @user2815899 `result1.setText(String.valueOf(r1)+"inches")`. append to your string not the method

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting an error with it.Can you how me how I would implement it in the class?

Comment: `String.valueOf(round(marks1,2))`. `round(marks1,2)` gives you double right. then this `String.valueOf(round(marks1,2))` gives you string right. all you need to do is append your string to `String.valueOf(round(marks1,2))`. it gives me error? what is the error? and how did you use my suggestion?

Comment: Oh,I understand now,it would be `result1.setText(String.valueOf(round(mark1,2))+"inches");` Danke :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
result1.setText(String.ValueOf(round(mark1,2)));
result2.setText(String.ValueOf(round(mark2,2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        result1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark1);
        result2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mark2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        double mark1 = intent.getDoubleExtra("number1", 0);
        double mark2 = intent.getDoubleExtra("number2", 0);

        result1.setText(round(mark1,2));
        result2.setText(round(mark2,2));
    }

    public static String round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        return String.valueOf(bd.doubleValue());
    }
```